# praw.Reddit crashes the script

Tags: python, praw

Well, I am doing a small Reddit bot,

and for some reason, whenever I do:

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='shiftnotifier/0.11 by app1enerd')
```

It just crashes the script. I am running it on Windows Server 2012.

What can I do?

Comment: "It just crashes the script" is very vague; for starters, what is the traceback that you get?

Comment: Perhaps you are being blocked by reddit. Make sure that you are obeying the [API Guidelines](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API)

Answer (score 0):

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='shiftnotifier/0.11 by app1enerd')
```

In order to log into reddit you need 5 values:

1. username - username of account
2. password - password of account
3. client_id - the id of the app that you created (or will now create) on the account (it's a long string of gibberish right under the app name)(to create an app go to preferences->apps->create a new app)
4. client_secret - the secret string of your app (psst, keep it secret)
5. user_agent - the stuff you already put

You need all 5 in order for it to work...